# Append Enum Flags to a Parameter C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have the enum below:

```
[Flags]
public enum SearchType
{
    NONE = 0,
    LOGIN = 1,
    CREATION_DATE = 2,
    FIRST_LOGIN_DATE = 3,
    LAST_LOGIN_DATE = 4,
    STATUS = 5
}
```

And my function to append the flag to a String Builder:

```
StringBuilder SearchFlagNames = new StringBuilder();

SearchFlagNames.Append(UserDAO.SearchType.LOGIN).Append(", ");
SearchFlagNames.Append(UserDAO.SearchType.CREATION_DATE).Append(", ");
```

And in the last, the cast:

```
UserDAO.SearchType SearchFlags = UserDAO.SearchType.NONE;

string flags = SearchFlagNames.ToString().Trim().TrimEnd(',');
SearchFlags |= (UserDAO.SearchType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserDAO.SearchType), flags);
```

The tests and the errors:

1. Select 'LOGIN' and 'CREATION_DATE', SearchFlags variable will be set in 'FIRST_LOGIN_DATE'
2. Select 'FIRST_LOGIN_DATE' and 'LAST_LOGIN_DATE', SearchFlags variable will be set in 'CREATION_DATE' and 'STATUS'

I don't know what wrong I'm doing.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: the values in a flags enum should be powers of two, as in 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384 and so on. The logical operators that work on flags would not work as expected when this is not the case. As it is currently written, `FIRST_LOGIN_DATE` would be a combination of `LOGIN | CREATION_DATE` which makes no sense.

Comment: Why don't you just call `searchTypeVariable.ToString()`?

Comment: this would not work with their enum as it is currently defined, because the [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,795) of `Enum.ToString()` follows "If for each bit that is set in the value there is a corresponding constant (a pure power of 2), then the OR string (eg. "Red | Yellow") is returned. Otherwise, if the value is zero or if you can't create a string that consists of pure powers of 2 OR-ed together, you return a hex value". OP goes for comma+space as a separator.